# Вывести ассоциативный массив

Tags: php

Не могу понять как вывести fetch_assoc()

```
$Prices_bd = $mysqli->query("SELECT ask FROM `coinInfo` WHERE 'coinName'='ccc'")->fetch_assoc();
echo '<pre>';
       var_dump ($Prices_bd);
echo '</pre>';
```

Всегда выдает null

Comment: И так и будет пока не разберетесь что значат кавычки в тексте запроса.

Comment: у вас таблица в апострофах, а поле `coinName` в одинарных кавычках. это ок?